# How can I escape a number at the beginning of a CSS identifier?

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors, identifier

I am trying to code a [fallback of `getElementsByClassName` with `querySelectorAll` for IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21566726/1529630).

The problem comes with classes which start with a number.

I know identifiers can't begin with a number, so `querySelectorAll` throws an error. But `getElementsByClassName` accepts them.

Then, is there a way of escaping those numbers?

Comment: "[In CSS2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html) .. to make ".55ft" a valid class, CSS2 requires the first digit to be escaped (".\35 5ft")"

Comment: Why? There are enough `getElementsByClassName` polyfills available, so don't reinvent the wheel!

Comment: @Bergi Because they don't work like I want. And thanks for fixing the typo

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela The questions are almost the same, but I was referring to a JavaScript way of escaping (see I used javascript tag but the other question didn't). And maybe it won't be trivial to pass from other question's answers to a javascript approach, for someone who doesn't know JS very well. Then I'm not sure if it should be closed as duplicate.

Comment: This is a specific implementation question, and, well, everything else you just said @Oriol. So I reopened it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution!

Identifiers can't start with a digit, but can start with an unicode [escaped](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-syntax/#escaping) digit (see [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21229901/1529630)).

Then, I can use

```
.replace(/\b\d/g, function(match){return '\\0000' + match.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);})
```

The code above escapes characters whose unicode code has two digits in hexadecimal. But for numbers, the following also works:

```
.replace(/\b\d/g, '\\00003$&')
```