# How to style a class starting with 0

Tags: css, wordpress, class

A WP theme I am amending has 5 columns, all 5 have a class of `span3 mbtm feature`, but they also have classes of `first`, `0.25`, `0.5`, `0.75` and `last` respectively.

I only want to add CSS to the middle column, how do I target a class that begins with a number?

Comment: have you tried adding a class to the HTML template?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS classes with names that start with numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227702/css-classes-with-names-that-start-with-numbers)

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Thank you, so would a class of 0.5, i presume the . is a whitespace character, what would the CSS selector be please, its a bit confusing, thank you.

Comment: The period is not whitespace, but since it has a special meaning in CSS, it needs to be escaped when it is part of a class name. For `class=0.5`, a suitable selector is `.\30\.5`. The `\30` is escape for digit zero, and `\.` is escape for the period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got to it using `parent > div:nth-of-type(3)`

Answer (score 2):

Check this excellent article by ben frain on the topic: http://benfrain.com/when-and-where-you-can-use-numbers-in-id-and-class-names/

Your css should look like

```
div[class=0.5] {
    background-color: #0f0; 
}
```

Although you can escape the characters, imo you should not use it for the sake of readability.