# css style not getting applied to guid css class selector

Tags: css, styles, backend, selector

Im trying to have some backend code generate some styling for me, and it prints the css class and style just fine.
following style is printed at the top of the page.

```
.655c6933-5ae9-4089-a576-df528bf6c823 {
     
    background-color:#f2f2f2;
}
```

and as you can see in the image below the class on the html is identical, but the style issent applied, and when I add a custom style in chrome the css selector is article.\36 55c6933-5ae9-4089-a576-df528bf6c823.

this is quid confusing and I can't figure out where this /36 space is comming from ?

[image]

here you can see and test the problem as well:
https://jsfiddle.net/569r1p7x/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS class starting with number is not getting applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45293534/css-class-starting-with-number-is-not-getting-applied)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45293575/2023687) in regards to classes that start with numbers.

To get around this, the following works for me;

```
<style>
.\36 55c6933-5ae9-4089-a576-df528bf6c823 {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
</style>
```

And...

```
<article class="655c6933-5ae9-4089-a576-df528bf6c823">Hello World</article>
```

The `\36` represents the number `6` which is the first character in your CSS class. The number `6` is removed from the CSS declaration in replacement for the escaped version.

Comment: I i didn't know this was a thing at all !
So I could just add a custome name at first like theming-655c6933-5ae9-4089-a576-df528bf6c823 then it woulden matter I guess ? :)

Comment: Yes, correct. That would solve it. Ideally all CSS classes should start with `a-z` characters (imo, best practice).

Comment: Thank you Daze for answering my question!