# Css class only works if I add a random digit in front of it

Tags: html, css

I ran into some bizzare CSS behavior when I was refactoring my style tags into a separate CSS file.  Here is my HTML; the "parentOfViewCommentsLink" is the specific class that's acting strange.

```
            <div class="parentOfViewCommentsLink" style="height=20%">
                <span ng-show="image.description">{{ image.description }}  </span>
                <div ng-hide="image.description" class="noDescription">No Description Found</div>
                <!-- <div data-ng-click="vm.navToComments()">Comments</div> -->
                <div class="viewCommentsLink" ng-click="vm.viewComments()">View {{image.comments.length}} Comments</div>
                <div class="{{vm.flagClass}}" ng-click="vm.flagged()"> </div>
                <!--<div class="ion-archive" ng-click="vm.downloadMoment(image)"> </div>-->
            </div>
```

and my CSS:

```
/* Comments */
.viewCommentsLink {
  position: absolute; 
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;  
}

.parentViewCommentsLink {
  position: relative;
}
```

This HTML/CSS produced this bizzare result:

[image]

Scratching my head at this strange behavior because it just worked - All I did was extract my style tags into a CSS file.  After playing around with it I was able to fix it!

[image]

How you might ask?  Well I threw a '2' in front of the class name:

```
<div class="2parentViewCommentsLink" style="height=20%">
                <span ng-show="image.description">{{ image.description }}  </span>
                <div ng-hide="image.description" class="noDescription">No Description Found</div>
                <!-- <div data-ng-click="vm.navToComments()">Comments</div> -->
                <div class="viewCommentsLink" ng-click="vm.viewComments()">View {{image.comments.length}} Comments</div>
                <div class="{{vm.flagClass}}" ng-click="vm.flagged()"> </div>
                <!--<div class="ion-archive" ng-click="vm.downloadMoment(image)"> </div>-->
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Comments */
.viewCommentsLink {
  position: absolute; 
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;  
}

.2parentViewCommentsLink {
  position: relative;
}
```

I have no idea why this worked or why it would even make a difference.  I do not have another class name parentOfViewCommentsLink anywhere and at this point I'm just curious as to why this even worked.  Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: "I've also tried "parentViewCommentsLink", "viewCommentsLinkParent" niether of which worked

Comment: text please instead of images

Comment: My guess is that parentOfViewCommentsLink  has different styles somewhere else, which cause this behavior. Hence, when you use a completely different css class, the issue is fixed indirectly.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but `style=30px` should be `style: 30px`

Comment: Removing `position: relative;` altogether might fix the issue as well.

Comment: You mention `parentOfViewCommentsLink` in the text of the question (just before the first snippet of code) and, within that snippet of HTML, the `<div>` element has the class attribute set to: `parentViewCommentsLink` There seems to be a missing, or surplus, `Of` in one of those strings.

Comment: Thats a typo, someone asked me to replace my pictures with actual code.  I'll go fix it

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I don't actually need parentViewCommentsLink at all.  In fact HAVING the class is causing the issue.

In addition, if you add a number in front of a CSS class it becomes invalid.  So since I put a number in front of the CSS class it became invalid and it worked because I never even needed the class.

And not adding a number made the class valid which broke it.  It was doing more harm than good.

Bizzare situation.  Thanks for your help reguardless.

Comment: Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227702/is-there-a-workaround-to-make-css-classes-with-names-that-start-with-numbers-val/21229901#21229901 . It explains properly what is and is not valid with regard to digits at the start of class names.

Comment: Was just about to ask what happened if you escaped the digit in the CSS file (`.\2parentViewCommentsLink {...`). You can use digits (or virtually any other character in class names if you escape them.

Comment: @steveax Ehm, no. `.\2...` does not match a class starting with 2. If you want to match a 2 at the beginning, you should write `.\32...`

Answer (score -1):

We've got way too little info to give you an accurate answer.

Most likely there are additional rules being applied to the element.
Inspect the element and look for the css rules.

All modern browsers come with dev tools. right click the element and choose inspect, a window will pop up which will help you debug css issues.
[image]

Once you know WHY it's being displayed like that, you can go hunt for the relevant rules. They might be in some other file and being overwritten due to import order.